# Access VM virtual host site

Tags: virtual-machine

Ok, my situation is:

I have a Mac with Parallels running Windows 7. On this Windows 7 VM i have pointed exampledomain.com to 127.0.0.1 via the hosts file. What I would like to do is when I'm on my Mac, is to be able to browse exampledomain.com and see exactly what the VM sees.

I have tried all the usual hosts file combos, but I can ping exampledomain.com and do receive a response from my VM but I cannot browse to it in a browser.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

my VM has an IP of 192.168.1.120 and my Mac an IP of 192.168.1.92

Comment: So redirect the domain to the address of your mac not the localhost which is virtual machine itself.

Comment: @Ramhound but my VM has an IP of 192.168.1.120 and my Mac an IP of 192.168.1.92

Comment: So you have everything you need to do what you want.  You just to make sure to configure the virtual machine so it can ping the host operating system.